validate object in pydantic 1.x where values are sometimes camelCase and sometimes PascalCase
Having the following object
{'d': {'results': [
    {'superHeroPublicId': '1', 
     'power': '100.00', 
     'infoText': 'irrelevant'}, 
    {
     'SuperHeroPublicId': '2', 
     'Power': '1541.60', 
     'InfoText': 'irrelevant'} ]}}

And the following customization of the pydantic's BaseModel
class ApiPublicBaseModel(BaseModel):
class Config:
    alias_generator = camelize
    allow_population_by_field_name = True
    extra = Extra.ignore
    json_encoders = {
        datetime: lambda value: value.isoformat(),
    }

Assuming that I can't change the ApiPublicBaseModel written in pydantic v1, how can I create a model that doesn't crash when I try to validate objects? This camelCase / PascalCase is driving me crazy.

A few approaches here:

Create a root_validator  with pre=True to manipulate the json object before the model is instantiated.
(If you can't add validators to the model) Create multiple class definitions and validate using a union

For the 1st option:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, root_validator


class ApiPublicBaseModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True

    ...

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def coerce_casing(cls, values):
        
        if "SuperHeroPublicId" in values:
            values["superHeroPublicId"] = values.pop("SuperHeroPublicId")
    
        return values


2nd option is a bit wonky in V1 (much neater in V2 with discriminated union):
class ApiPublicBaseModel1(BaseModel):
    super_hero_public_id: str = Field(alias="superHeroPublicId")

class ApiPublicBaseModel2(BaseModel):
    super_hero_public_id: str = Field(alias="SuperHeroPublicId")

class AnotherModel(BaseModel):
    __root__: Union[ApiPublicBaseModel1, ApiPublicBaseModel2]


m1 = AnotherModel.parse_obj(dict(superHeroPublicId="foo"))
m2 = AnotherModel.parse_obj(dict(SuperHeroPublicId="foo"))
assert m1.__root__ == m2.__root__ 

